# need to run many queries in different time slots

Tags: .net, oracle

Need suggestions to build .net tool which runs SQL queries according to the time slot specified in the oracle table(see below example for more info).
suggestions can be on both .net and oracle.

I have a requirement to run multiple queries in different time slots.
queries are stored in a oracle table with the time specified to repeat.. each query has to run in separate time slot.
example,

```
select * from employees ;--> query 1
select * from students ;--> query 2
select * from department; --> query 3
```

all above 3 queries are stored in a oracle table.

```
table name : queries,
query   repeat_at(in minutes)
query1  10
query2  15
query3  20
```

need to build a .net application which runs each queries at specified time slot..tool will be scheduled in task scheduler.

Comment: select * from employees ;--> query 1
select * from students ;--> query 2
select * from department; --> query 3
all above 3 queries are stored in a oracle table.
table name : queries,
query   repeat_at(in minutes)
query1  10
query2  15`enter code here`
query3  20

Comment: I need to suggestions to build such .net tool

Comment: You want `[.Net]` advice not `[Oracle]` advice? Or both? Please **edit your question** to clarify exactly what problem you have and what help you want. *"suggestions"* is too vague and your question will be closed as either Unclear or Too Broad.

Comment: need suggestions to build .net tool to run those queries at specified time slot.
if query 1 is complete  then it should run only after 15 mins
if query 2 is complete  then it should run only after 10 mins

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what those "queries" really do (because, running what you showed us doesn't make much sense).

If they do some processing, put them into PL/SQL procedures and schedule them via Oracle's `DBMS_JOB` or, preferably, `DBMS_SCHEDULER`. Doing so, you'd avoid

- .Net application
- operating system's Task scheduler

and do everything within the database.

If you're on 18c, you can even schedule operating system's .SQL script (have a look at the `JOB_TYPE` parameter) (which allows you to run `select * from employees`, but I don't know what you'd do with it).

Comment: .net tool is what preferred.
if any of the those queries returns the count which is more than 15 then the .net tool should create a ticket (notification to support team saying to take a look at the stock)

Comment: Why can't the pl/sql procedure create the ticket?

Comment: my bad, clients are not agreeing that approach

Comment: Ah. Clients. Why do they care? From their point of view, job has to be done. The way you do it, it is *your* job.